# laravel 5.2 internal server error

Tags: php, web-hosting, laravel-5, shared-hosting

My laravel project work good in localhost by `artisan serve` commend. 
Now i'm trying to host it on web host. 
I upload my project under `public_html` and copy all files from `public` folder i also edit `app.php` `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),` for showing the error.

i edit index.php

```
require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

but it still give a 500 Internal server error back.

I also try an another way,
Upload my project into root directory except `public` folder and upload `public` folder into `public_html` directory . 
and i edit `index.php` as

```
require __DIR__.'/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

i can't find what wrong with my code. 
how can i deploy my laravel 5.2 project into a web hosting.?

Comment: What do your server logs say?  PHP, Apache, Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

No No no.. You need to achieve the second option with some improvements. Let me explain it to you. A laravel application looks like:

```
app/
config/
public/
public/index.php
.env
composer.json
artisan
```

Right? good, now a web host's structure looks like:

```
/home/user/
/home/user/public_html/
```

But the structure above does not fit our needs because is `public/` folder that should be accessed instead of `public_html/`. So.. the first step is to upload your project, lets say, like these:

```
/home/user/home/project/app/
/home/user/project/config/
/home/user/project/.env
/home/user/project/composer.json
/home/user/project/public/index.php
```

The next step is decide if you want your project as a main domain, or as subdomain.

1. If your laravel's project will serve as a main domain just edit apache's config file `httpd.conf` and set the following rules:

   DocumentRoot "/home/user/project/public"

   ...
2. If you want you project as a subdomain, just edit the apache's config file `httpd.conf` and add a virtual server like this:

   ```
   Listen 80
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       DocumentRoot "/home/user//project/public"
       ServerName my-project.example.com

       # Other directives here
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

   With this directive you are telling to apache `Hey! when people visits my-project.example.com show them the content of my site under /home/user/site/public`.

   > IF you are using cpanel, just create a subdomain and point it to `/home/user/site/public`

That is all, you do not need to hack any project's files like index.php, that is a bad practice.

Comment: I am creating subdomain for it by using cpanel but it is not pointing to anything else then public_html/ , please guide me on this

Comment: @NeerajRathod, while you are creating the subdomain there is a text field where you can set the path for point it

Comment: yes there is a text field with "public_html/" written in it, I had removed "public_html/" and write the desired pointing address, but after creating subdomain, I see pointing address is started only with "public_html/" continue with what I had written in the text field

Comment: Could you see the httpd.conf file an see if the virtual host was created?

Comment: I resolve it by referring this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242227/laravel-5-is-not-working-on-shared-hosting?noredirect=1#comment69688543_41242227