# Laravel 5 is not working on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel-5, shared-hosting

I have tested my Laravel 5 project on localhost its working fine with this url - http://localhost/project-name/public/

Then I uploaded my project on shared hosting, I have made desirable changes for database on .env file then trying to access it with the url - http://companysite.com/folder/innerFolder/public/

but not working and getting 500 internal server error

I have gone through with other questions with the related but no answer lead me to my solution. I have done following steps

- upload my project on root directory parallel to public_html
- update to project/public/index.php
- try to create subdomain pointing to my project but didn't succeed

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at
>   webmaster@techphant.techphant.com to inform them of the time this
>   error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: is the apache error log showing anything?

Comment: have you restart server ?

Comment: @atoms No error log is not showing anything?

Comment: I am using sharing hosting and I think I don't have the privilege to restart it. if you know how to then tell me @VforVendetta

Comment: try giving permission 777 to storage and vendor folder..

Comment: This both folder has permission 755 already @Jaimin

Comment: try 777 once @NeerajRathod

Comment: tried not working @Jaimin

Comment: check the forum http://laravel.io/forum/03-06-2015-how-to-setup-laravel-5-in-shared-hosting

Comment: You **have to** read what is in your web server log file. It contains information about what went wrong. Maybe it's a missing extension, maybe it's wrong PHP version, maybe it's something else. Ignore these stupid chmod 777 suggestions, anyone who suggests that should reconsider their career as programmer, you people are really terrible developers if the solution is `chmod 777` instead of **reading what the web server log says**.

Comment: @Mjh web server log is not saying any nothing, Nothing has updated in log file

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile thanks your link taken me out from the hell, Transform your comment to answer I'll upvote it. Thank you again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have referred this link [laravel.io](http://laravel.io/forum/03-06-2015-how-to-setup-laravel-5-in-shared-hosting)

Finally, I did the job on my shared hosting. This is what I did

1. Setup a project Laravel 5 in localhost correctly configured
2. Double check the server configuration of PHP 5.4 (this because every
   little change on .htaccess file may change that config)
3. Create a directory in the same level of public_html and put the
   project inside of that folder.
4. Put the content of public (L5) directly on public_html (be aware of
   don't overwrite the .htaccess file accidentally)

Now... This is the "tricky part"... I see this structure

mail

perl5

php

public_html

[framework-folder]

ssl

Inside of public_html I can see all the files of public directory of Laravel 5
Go to index.php and edit the line 22

> From this
>   **require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';**
>   To this
>   **require __DIR__.'/../[framework-folder]/bootstrap/autoload.php';**

And the line 36

> From this
>   **$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';**
>   To this
>   **$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../[framework-folder]/pulcro/bootstrap/app.php';**

The final step is to edit the .htaccess file and add some lines

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

and update [framework-folder]/server.php

> From this
>   **require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';**
>   To this
>   **require_once __DIR__.'/public_html/index.php';**

Refresh the cache of my browser and.. Victory!!
I know that this is not the absolute right way to install the framework (God, I never spoke about Composer)
But... It's working for me now
Hope that this can help somebody in order to deploy Laravel 5

Answer (score 1):

thanks to Neeraj Rathod, but I found this article more useful, and of course simple more!

[WHY AM I GETTING A 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR MESSAGE?](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644990/why-am-i-getting-a-500-internal-server-error-message)

in my case, by reading that article I found out from my "error pages" that the "group writable" permission must not be set for "index.php" file inside "public" folder and also for all folders through route. also you have to check that your shared hosting php version is more than 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Everything Neeraj Rathod said, but also go to your project in `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php`

In line number 1337, you can find the below code inside the `addWhereExistsQuery` method

```
$this->wheres[] = compact('type', 'operator', 'query', 'boolean');
```

you just remove the `'operator'` parameter.

Thanks to  this link:
[compact(): Undefined variable: operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56726263/compact-undefined-variable-operator) 
now my laravel test project blog is online.