# compact(): Undefined variable: operator

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting the following error

```
  (1/1) ErrorException
  compact(): Undefined variable: operator
```

This is my line of code

```
$postsCat = Post::whereHas('Cat', function($query) use ($sreachWord) {
    return $query->whereRaw('name REGEXP"'.sql_text_to_regx($sreachWord).'"');
})->orderBy('top','desc')
->orderBy('updated_at','desc')
->paginate(30);
```

Why is this happening? Is it because of my PHP version (7.3) or something else?

Comment: Are you on Laravel 5.4 and PHP 7.3?

Comment: Yep - PHP7.3 made this breaking change.  We've got a lot of code that this affects - we're not going to go back and fix, so stuck with 7.2 on a ton of legacy systems unfortunately.  You can set the variable to null and 7.3 will accept it.

Comment: @Bogdan yes same version

Comment: run "composer update" command can fix it.

Comment: Likely caused by use of an undefined variable in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php. While php7.2 didn't care about that (security issue at least), php7.4 throws an error.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Go to your project in

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php
```

On line number 1337, you can found below code inside the `addWhereExistsQuery` method

```
$this->wheres[] = compact('type', 'operator', 'query', 'boolean');
```

You just remove the 'operator' parameter.

And I hope it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you, @Hasanur.  In my case the defective code was found on line 1229 of `Builder.php`.  After studying that code I removed `operator` as you recommend and the call to `addWhereExistsQuery()` ran successfully.  However, I think you should add that this is a workaround only for this particular instance of the larger issue reported here: that of PHP 7.3+ rejecting undefined variables.

Comment: yesssssss, just remove the 'operator' paramiter ,,,, thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks a lot... you have saved my day.. @Hasanur 
Kareimovich you should accept it if work for you too.

Comment: This is hacky solution, and should be used only if it is not possible to update Laravel version for some reason.

Comment: @Hasanur Rahman Himel . I have also this issue , exploring from last two hours . Here is exact solution I found . Thanks for saving my time. In my case it is 1229 line.

Comment: this is not the right way as the given file can be overwrite with any update.
"composer update" will solve this issue

Comment: @AkashSethi 
The solution doesn't work in Laravel 8, the parameter isn't there anymore, and the problem persists. Have you stumbled upon an updated solution?

Comment: I have did that but not Perfect solution because error went to gammer.php in same word operator.....!

Comment: No, no, no. _Never_ modify any files within the **vendor** directory! This is terrible advice, and don’t know why it has been upvoted as many times as it has.

Answer (score 9):

There are 2 fixes for this issue

1. Downgrade your php to 7.2
2. run "composer update" as in latest Laravel this issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 8):

Please refer to this
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26936

The version of Laravel would need to be updated.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of passing the variable to the `compact()` method, you'll passe it the name of the variable as a string without the dollar symbol.

```
$postsCats = Post::all(); // example

return view('posts.index', compact('postsCats'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $posts = Post::latest()->get();
            return view('author.post.index', compact('posts'));
```

Comment: While your code snippet may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how your code snippet works improves its long-term value.

Comment: I found @Hasanur Rahman Himel's answer more complicated, hence this   `$posts` just matches  `posts` in compact(). And this is pretty enough

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to upgrade your Laravel, you just could change your Query to RAW query, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Latest PHP version doesn't allow use of undefined variables. Instead of removing the latest version, another option is to switch between versions. Install earlier version say **PHP7.2** as outlined [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62708162) Then set this as the preferred version by running `sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2` on your Ubuntu terminal. Then run `composer update`