# Apache start libphp7.3.so not found

Tags: apache2

I have Install php 7.3 and apache2 but when I try to start apache2 , I have this error :

```
service apache2 start

apache2: Syntax error on line 146 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.3.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.3.so into server:   /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I really don't know how to resolve this problem, I have tried to remove and reinstall without success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**It solved my problem:**

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install php7.3`
4. `sudo apt-get install php7.3-cli php7.3-common php7.3-json php7.3-opcache  php7.3-mysql php7.3-mbstring  php7.3-zip php7.3-fpm php7.3-intl php7.3-simplexml`
5. `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 35):

You're getting that error because the PHP 7.3 library for Apache is not installed.

```
sudo apt install -y libapache2-mod-php7.3
```

The above command should fix it.

Comment: Actually this is the exact solution for missing /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.3.so file

Comment: Agreed. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that I did not install apache tools for php.
On arch linux:

`yaourt -S php-apache`

After that, module appeared in the folder.

The best way not to make a mistake is to follow guide: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Apache_HTTP_Server#PHP

Answer (score -1):

Just copy the .so file from anotherplace