# Laravel 5.6: ErrorException: compact(): Undefined variable: operator

Tags: php, laravel, upgrade, laravel-5.6

I am upgrading my `laravel` from `5.5` to `5.6`. and upon running tests, I am getting this error:

> ErrorException: compact(): Undefined variable: operator

Now there is a solution present here [Laravel - compact(): Undefined variable: operator in Builder.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58915575/laravel-compact-undefined-variable-operator-in-builder-php) but I am following that very solution and still facing that error. Earlier I was upgrading from `5.4` to `5.6` then upon seeing the solution mentioned in the above question, I upgraded from `5.4` to `5.5` and now trying to upgrade from `5.5` to `5.6`.

Here is a little piece of code that is causing this error:

```
$query = TransportOrder::with('orderNumber');

$query->whereHas('orderNumber', function ($q) use ($orderNumber) {
      $q->where('order_number', '=', $orderNumber);
});

return $query->first();
```

That `whereHas` is causing this problem. So is there an alternate to `whereHas` and `with` or there is any other solution that I am missing?

My php version is this:

```
PHP 7.3.23-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Oct  6 2020 11:36:27) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.23, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.23-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with blackfire v1.24.2~linux-x64-non_zts73, https://blackfire.io, by Blackfire
```

EDIT:

`compact()` is used in `vendor` class `Builder`:

```
public function addWhereExistsQuery(self $query, $boolean = 'and', $not = false)
    {
        $type = $not ? 'NotExists' : 'Exists';

        $this->wheres[] = compact('type', 'operator', 'query', 'boolean');

        $this->addBinding($query->getBindings(), 'where');

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: I am not using compact in my code it is in vendor files. @KamleshPaul I have updated the question.

Comment: `$this->wheres[] = compact('type', 'operator', 'query', 'boolean');` this line is causing error it expect to have variable

Comment: try `$not = false` to `$operator = false` may be that you want

Comment: @KamleshPaul this is vendor file, I dont want to change it.

Comment: remove that library then .

Comment: What is the full version you're upgrading to? For Laravel 5.6, this was fixed in 5.6.34. I don't know how you're upgrading your application, but make sure you're upgrading to at least this version.

Comment: downgrade your php version or update the vendor code to solve the issue.

Comment: @patricus I am upgrading to 5.6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out upgrading laravel to 6.5.40 did the trick, as the mentioned issue was not resolved in the earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

If:

1. You can't upgrade Laravel for whatever business/team related reason and
2. Are sure that the Homestead box is running the correct version of PHP (7.2 or lower based on the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70916998)) and yet
3. are still getting this error,

explicitly define the PHP version on the Homestead.yaml file. This should be done on the sites property as such (each is a new line, of course):

`map: test.appp`
`/home/vagrant/code/test/public`
`php: "7.1"`